# Why does a template have to be declared before every function that uses one?

Tags: c++, templates

Why is the following code valid

```
template<class T>
T AddThree(T input)
{
    return input + 3;
}

template<class T>    // If I remove this line it won't compile
T SubtractThree(T input)
{
    return input - 3;
}
```

But if I comment out the line indicated it won't compile? How come the compiler doesn't still know about `template<class T>` from the first time it is declared (like anything else declared in the body of the file)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of it as part of the function signature. Maybe it's easier to see the connection if you write the full declaration on one line:

```
template<class T> T AddThree(T input)
{
    return input + 3;
}
```

It is like how you need to declare the parameters for each function. You would not expect this to work:

```
std::string AddThree(std::string input)
{
    return input + "3";
}

std::string SomethingElse(input)
{
    // ...
}
```

Here, like with the template parameters, you need to declare `input` in the second function as well as the first. It is the scoping rules of the language :)

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought about the fact that the line declaring the template is actually just part of the function declaration :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice the position of declaration terminators (semi-colons or function bodies). `template <class T>` is not a declaration by itself—it's not something that would be in scope for the entire file. It's part of the declaration of the function template in question.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought about the declaration terminators - I was thinking that `template<class T>` was a declaration by itself.

Answer (score 1):

How would the compiler know that `SubtractThree` is a templated function? Clearly you don't want a single template declaration to mean *everything* afterword is a template. You could also imagine designing the C++ spec such that every unrecognized class (T in this case) is seen as a template, but then you risk making template functions when you misspell classes.